# i need to update the column in the table has aaa@gmail.com

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column named `email`. I inserted into values like `aaaaa`. I need to update all the columns into `aaa@gmail.com`.

How to write a query for this? Please suggest.

Comment: You inserted `aaaaa` and want to update for `aaa@gmail.com`? How is related 5 x `a` with 3 x `a`? Provide more clearly sample data. And what do you meant `so i need to update all the columns...`? Do you meant all the values?

Comment: you can use regular expression for this I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you have stored emails in following:

```
Email
foo
bar
foobar
```

And want to update all the values like:

```
Email
foo@gmail.com
bar@gmail.com
foobar@gmail.com
```

You could use `UPDATE` in following:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Email = Email + '@gmail.com'
```

If you want to affect only rows where `Email = 'aaaaa'` you could add `WHERE` clause in following:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Email = Email + '@gmail.com'
WHERE Email = 'aaaaa'
```

Comment: Note that `+` is MS SQL Server specific concatenation. ANSI SQL has `||`.

Comment: sir i have one more problem

Comment: i have table  in that table  pancardnumber column is their. i need only which number is order that means the pancard number has four alphabets and four numbers and one alphabet so this order numbers only i want how to write a query.

Comment: @srinath provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

To what i am understanding you want to add "gmail.com" to all your texts, what you can do is make a Varchar to store your text which is "aaaaa" and another Varchar for the "gmail.com" then you concatenate both together.